# How can I group and sort columns in spark.rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I currently have a dataframe like this

```
+------------+----------+----------+
|         mac|time      |s         |
+------------+----------+----------+
|aaaaaaaaaaaa|11        |a         |
|aaaaaaaaaaaa|44        |c         |
|bbbbbbbbbbbb|22        |b         |
|aaaaaaaaaaaa|33        |a         |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

I want use the .rdd funcition and group by the column "mac" and sort by the column "time",here is an example

```
res5: Array[(Any, Iterable[(Any, Any)])] = Array((aaaaaaaaaaaa,CompactBuffer((11,a),(33,a),(44,c))), (bbbbbbbbbbbb,CompactBuffer((22,b))))
```

I already can groupby column "mac" but still can't sort by "time"

```
df.rdd.map(x=>(x(0),(x(1),x(2)))).groupByKey()
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your required output? Also try to avoid groupByKey https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: Why do you want to convert it rdd and then do the operation? Instead you can achieve this by using window function on dataframe. Is there any specific output format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  df.rdd.map(x=>(x(0),(x(1),x(2)))).groupByKey()
     .mapValues(_.toSeq.sortBy(_._1.asInstanceOf[Int]))
```

Comment: This helped.Thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     |       ("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 11, "a"),("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 44, "c"),("bbbbbbbbbbb", 22, "b"),("aaaaaaaaaaaa", 33, "a")
     |     ).toDF("mac", "time","s")
scala> df.rdd.sortBy(_.apply(1).toString).groupBy(_.apply(0)).collect
res38: Array[(Any, Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])] = Array((aaaaaaaaaaaa,CompactBuffer([aaaaaaaaaaaa,11,a], [aaaaaaaaaaaa,33,a], [aaaaaaaaaaaa,44,c])), (bbbbbbbbbbbb,CompactBuffer([bbbbbbbbbbbb,22,b])))
```

Thanks

Comment: Nice and smart answer as always. Thanks!